# JavaFx + Spring + Sqlite (Closed)

Tags: spring, sqlite, javafx, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I always worked with web application, but now I need to create one desktop. I need to integrate JavaFx with spring and use sqlite. Someone have an exemple of datasource configuration or even one small application that implements that all?

---

Solved! I used Springboot with H2 database.

Comment: Your question is pretty much [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for this forum, but fwiw:  my [JavaFX + Spring blog post](http://www.marshall.edu/genomicjava/2015/09/27/experiments-with-spring-and-javafx/). There are many others. No datasource config there, but that is fairly standard...

Answer (score 0):

this is a example of conection class for Sqlite i hope it helps

```
   //Variables a utilizar
    private static final String DRIVER   =  "org.sqlite.JDBC";
    private static final String JDBC_URL =  "jdbc:sqlite:src/Sqlite.db";
    Connection coneccion;

    /**
     * connects the database 
     */
    public Connection conectarBD(){
        try {
            Class.forName(DRIVER);
            this.coneccion = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL);
            if (this.coneccion != null) {
                System.out.println("connect to the  database ");
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ClassName.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ClassName.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
       return coneccion;
    }

    /**
     * Disconnect from the database 
     */
    public void desconectarBD(){
        try {
            coneccion.close();
            System.out.println("Disconnect from the database ");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ClassName.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

for managing the sqlite databese i recoment the program SQLiteStudio you can get it in here http://sqlitestudio.pl/